# Transforming 4 sum problem from non-recursive to recursive function

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, recursion, transform

I need to  implement a Recursive Function (which
accepts the Array and sum as parameters) to check if it contains four elements
having the given sum.

For Example:

int[] intArray = {12, 18, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5};

sum = 35

Output:
Quadruplet exists.

I created first non recursive function and then I tried to transform it to recursive function but it didn't work.

Here is my non recursive function:

```
public class NonRecursive4Sum {

  void FourElementsSum (int arr[], int n, int X)
    {
        // In first step we save first number and search for other 3
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 3; i++)
        {
            // Save 2. number and search for 2
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 2; j++)
            {
                // Save 3. and search for last one
                for (int k = j + 1; k < n - 1; k++)
                {
                    // Here we save last number
                    for (int l = k + 1; l < n; l++)
                    {
                        // This is the part I am trying to transform to recursive function
                        if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] + arr[l] == X){
                            System.out.print("Quadruplets exists");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NonRecursive4Sum findfour = new NonRecursive4Sum ();
        int[] intArray= {12, 18, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5};
       
        
        findfour.FourElementsSum(intArray, 8, 35);
    }
}
```

This is modified if statement that I am trying to transform to recursive function:

```
if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] + arr[l] != X){
                            FourElementsSum ();
                        }
                        else if(arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] + arr[l] == X) {
                            System.out.println("Quadruplets Exist");
                        }
```

Comment: Rather than posting here, if you jut google you can find the solution online:
https://www.techiedelight.com/4-sum-problem/

Comment: Thank you Shubham, I was just interested if its possible to create recursive function from for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an efficient solution - you can go to this [link](https://www.techiedelight.com/4-sum-problem/).

If you want to convert your for loops into a recursive function, you can try something like this:

```
public static boolean FourElementsSumRecursive (int arr[], int n, int X, int i, int j, int k, int l)
    {
        //reached the end. no sums add up to X
        if(i>=n-3 || j>=n-2 || k>=n-1 || l>=n){
            return false;
        }
        
        //Found a quadruplet
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] + arr[l] == X){
            return true;
        }
        
        
        //increase i, j, k, l for all combinations
        return FourElementsSumRecursive(arr, n, X, i+1, j, k, l) || FourElementsSumRecursive(arr, n, X, i, j+1, k, l) || FourElementsSumRecursive(arr, n, X, i, j, k+1, l) || FourElementsSumRecursive(arr, n, X, i, j, k, l+1);
    }

   
int X = 35;
boolean didFindQuadruplet = findfour.FourElementsSumRecursive(intArray, intArray.length, X, 0, 1, 2, 3); 
//true for X=35
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Shubham Periwal, this is working perfect.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer then? so it's no longer shown as an "unanswered question"

Comment: I am new on stack overflow, can you please tell me how to do that? Thank you

Comment: There must be a "tick" next to my answer on the left. If you can't find it, maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: I found it, I would vote up also but I still don't have voting privilege. Thanks a million again Shubham.